# How can I "tell" MySQL to return the maximum value for each category and some other value associated with that max value?

Tags: mysql, database, max

[Here I have my table called "Pais"(Country in Spanish), Id_Pais is the Primary Key and Continente_FK(Continente stands for Continent) is a foreign key that relates each country to a continent, below you can see my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D23me.png)

What I'm trying to do is a table that shows me by continent the maximum extension of a country AND the name of the country that has the max extension, I have done the first part already with these code:

```
SELECT MAX(Extension) FROM Pais GROUP BY Continente_FK;
```

That code shows me the max extension associated with each continent, I tried this other code, but it only shows me the max extension out of all countries, not the max for each continent(the max out of all):

```
SELECT C.Id_Continente, P.Nombre, P.Extension,C.Nombre
FROM Pais P RIGHT OUTER JOIN Continente C ON C.Id_Continente=P.Continente_FK 
WHERE P.Extension=(SELECT MAX(Extension) FROM Pais)
GROUP BY C.Id_Continente;
```

"Nombre" means "Name"

I really don't know how to tell MySQL to "give" the name that has associated the max extension, please help.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag on this forum. Sometimes it's correctly answered too. The good news is that you're half way there with that first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a condition in the subquery:

```
SELECT C.Id_Continente, P.Nombre, P.Extension,C.Nombre
FROM Pais P RIGHT OUTER JOIN Continente C 
ON C.Id_Continente=P.Continente_FK 
WHERE P.Extension=(SELECT MAX(Extension) FROM Pais P2
                   WHERE P2.Continente_FK = C.Id_Continente)
GROUP BY C.Id_Continente;
```

The only problem I see is if you have two countries from the same continent with same extension (which is unlikely). You'll always get one result per continent.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this problem in a different way (Using a JOIN) but it's good to know more than one way to solve it!